# What requirements are necessary in order to properly call getString(String key) function in a Wicket WebPage?

Tags: java, wicket, resourcebundle, getstring

I have one Wicket (6.19) bundle including:

- HomePage.java
- HomePage.html
- HomePage.properties.xml

In the `.java` file I have this code :

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
    public HomePage() {
        add(new Label("message", getString("greetingMessage")));
    }
}
```

and in the `.properties` file I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM
    "http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="greetingMessage">Hello</entry>
</properties>
```

The problem is that calling the `getString` method returns an exception :

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Unable to find property:
>   'greetingMessage' for component:  [class=com.mycompany.HomePage].
>   Locale: null, style: null

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console:

```
WARN - PropertiesFactory - Unable to find resource file:/.../HomePage.properties.xml
java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid system identifier: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/dtd/properties.dtd
```

So replace the doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
```

Comment: and what should i use instead , because the link is copied from their official website ?

Comment: it worked , i used  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd" instead , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Better use `add(new Label("message", new ResourceModel("greetingMessage")));`.

Also make sure the .properties.xml file is copied by your build tool to HomePage.class, so it is available later at runtime.

Comment: yes , it is copied and is available at runtime , adding ResourceModel instead of getString did not resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new Label("message", new StringResourceModel("greetingMessage", this, null).getString());
```